# How can one add a specific part of a binary tree but keep the tree intact (Java)?

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-data, binary-search

I am trying to write a code that searches a binary tree for an element and then adds starting at that element. So far I can find the correct position and add to that position, but I lose the rest of the binary tree.

```
    public void add(String addroot, String addleft)
      if(root!=nodesearch){
        if(root.left!=null){
          root=root.left;
          add(addroot, addleft);
        }
        if(root.right!=null){
          root=root.right;
          add(addroot, addleft);
        }
      }
      else
        root=insert();
    }
```

insert() adds the elements and it works fine. Thanks for any help.

Ok so this is what I'm thinking now.

```
private BinaryStringNode local_root = root
public void add()

  if(root!=nodesearch){
    if(local_root.left!=null){
      local_root=local_root.left;
      add();
    }
    if(local_root.right!=null){
      local_root=local_root.right;
      add();
    }
  }
  else
    local_root=insert();
}
```

Would local_root=insert() use the insert method on root at the position of local_root. Also would local_root=local_root.right move through root?

Comment: Dont Change the root! use a temp variable

Comment: How do I add to the root when I search with a temp variable?

Comment: in your add function, pass a "local_root" value, when ever you call the function the first time you pass root, but in ur recursive calls you should do add(local_root.right,addroot,addleft)

Comment: but how do I insert into the root at the position I found with local_root

Comment: In most cases, except for your base case root.right and root.left will already have values. So you want to go until a null right/left is found. When you do, you simply set null to your value

Comment: I edited to do what I think you are say. Is this right? Thanks Steven.

Comment: right, it should be a pointer

Answer (score 0):

First Make it three independent functions

```
void insert(BinaryStringNode root, BinaryStringNode new_node){

}

int add(BinaryStringNode root){

}

BinaryStringNode find(String name){

}
```

Now fill the code in as best you can.

When you want to get the sum just call `add(find(s));` where s is a string